# see if both values exists already in sqlite table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I know

```
cursor.execute("select * from table where value = ?",(user,))
```

checks to see if there is a name but, is there a way to check if both value 1 and value 2 exists in the table already?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use the `IN` operator, or the `OR` operator. For example:

```
cursor.execute("select * from table where value in (?, ?)",(user, otheruser)) 

cursor.execute("select * from table where value = ? or value = ?",(user, otheruser))
```

If that returns two rows, both exist.

If the values aren't unique (that is, there could be 20 rows for user and none for otheruser), this trick doesn't quite work—but you can fix that easily with a `DISTINCT` clause or a `GROUP BY`.

Also, you can just use `COUNT(*)` instead of returning multiple rows.

So:

```
def both_exist(user, otheruser):
    cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE value IN (?, ?) GROUP BY value", 
                   (user, otheruser))
    count, = cursor.fetchone()
    return count == 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AND operator

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE table_field1 = ? AND table_field2 = ?", (value1,value2))
result=cursor.fetchall()
if len(result)==0:
    print('Not found')
else:
    print('Found')
```